# How to use keyboard input declared in main() in other methods of the class containing it?

Tags: java, input

I'm not sure how to use

```
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);  //Keyboard input
```

which I declare in main() in other methods of the class containg it. I get "stdin cannot be resolved".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to learn about [variable scope](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm) (and here's a link to the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html), and [another on variable scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html)).

In order to use that variable in other methods, you need to pass a reference to your other methods.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);  // define a local variable ...
  foo(stdin);                              // ... and pass it to the method
}

private static void foo(Scanner stdin)
{
  String s = stdin.next();                 // use the method parameter
}
```

Alternatively, you could declare the scanner as a static field:

```
public class TheExample
{
  private static Scanner stdin;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    stdin = new Scanner(System.in);       // assign the static field ...
    foo();                                // ... then just invoke foo without parameters
  }

  private static void foo()
  {
    String s = stdin.next();              // use the static field
  }
}
```